# how to pass an onclick method to a radio button created using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am creating a radio button using makeRadioButton function, here I am passing the name and value, I also tried passing the name of a function the same way, and it doesn't seem to work. Please help me how to pass a function to a newly created radio button.

```
function makeRadioButton(name, value, text) {

   var label = document.createElement("label");
   var radio = document.createElement("input");
   radio.type = "radio";
   radio.name = name;
   radio.value = value;
   **radio.onclick = "createDropdown()";**
   label.appendChild(radio);
   label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
   return label;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine you just have to append your returned value to the document.

Try this example below

```js
    function makeRadioButton(name, value, text) {

       var label = document.createElement("label");
       var radio = document.createElement("input");
       radio.type = "radio";
       radio.name = name;
       radio.value = value;
       radio.onclick = createDropdown;
       label.appendChild(radio);
       label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
       return label;
    }

    let lable = makeRadioButton("myRadio", null, "How old are you");

    document.body.append(lable);


function createDropdown(){
console.log("CLICKED");

}
```

Comment: radio button is getting created, but when i inspect the element, there is no onclick attribute.

Comment: @Madhu I have fixed it don't assign it as string instead directly use the funcitonname

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `onclick` to directly be the function `createDropdown`:

```js
function makeRadioButton(name, value, text) {
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  var radio = document.createElement("input");
  radio.type = "radio";
  radio.name = name;
  radio.value = value;
  radio.onclick = createDropdown;
  label.appendChild(radio);
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  return label;
}

function createDropdown(event) {
  console.log("createDropdown");
};

document.body.appendChild(makeRadioButton("radio", null, "radio"));
```

Comment: The console shows that onclick is working, I will try to create a dropdown inside this createDropdown(event) and let you know how it goes, thank you